Publishing a Node.js module to npm from Windows Subsystem for Linux - handling authentication
I'm developing a Node.js module on WSL (Ubuntu on Windows). When I want to publish it I run npm adduser and that outputs
username@my-pc:/mnt/c/Users/username/workspace/demo-node$ npm adduser
npm notice Log in on https://registry.npmjs.org/
Create your account at:
https://www.npmjs.com/login?next=/login/cli/12345678-abcd-1234-6789-1234567890ab
Press ENTER to open in the browser...

But given this is WSL, I don't have a desktop environment. How have others solved this? Right now I reverted back to publishing from Windows.

Where is your problem? Copy the link & paste it in your browser. Not sure what you expect... But given this is WSL, I don't have a desktop environment I highly doubt that you are using a headless windows.

Pasting the link the browser won't work because the token from the device code flow won't end up in WSL

npm adduser --auth-type=legacy

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-adduser#auth-type
